# How to NOT respond at all to a request using koa 2?

Tags: node.js, koa, koa2

I want to implement a shadowban. Above a certain rate limit, I want to **not respond anything** to a request.

I couldn't find how to do that in the doc.

It seems setting `body = null` will still trigger a response.

How may I prevent koa@2 from answering to a request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this by setting `ctx.respond = false` in your route handler.

Having a look through `koa`'s source code shows this: [https://github.com/koajs/koa/blob/master/lib/application.js#L201](https://github.com/koajs/koa/blob/b9e35469d3bbd0a1ee92e0a815ce2512904d4a18/lib/application.js#L201)

```
function respond(ctx) {
  // allow bypassing koa
  if (false === ctx.respond) return;
  // ...
```